# How to compare an array of numbers with user input?

Tags: arrays, powershell, input, printing, compare

I have created 3 arrays, which store data from a separate file called household.dat, arr1 holds the ID, arr2 holds the income, and arr3 holds family members. The user is asked to enter an existent id (one that exists in the household file). If the id exists, I have to print the information related to that specific ID. The problem starts when I try to compare the user's input with the already stored id.
This is what I have so far.

- $myarr contains the first set of numbers in the first column which is the ID
- $myarr1 contains the second set of numbers in the second column, which is the income
- $myarr2 contains the third set of numbers in the third column which is the members

```
10041,12180.00,4
15298,89254.00,3
10562,13240.00,3
13256,19800.00,2
47742,67189.00,4
14830,22458.00,8
19000,17000.00,2
21132,18125.00,7
23541,15623.00,2
82772,56878.00,2
32100,3200.00,6
67733,98113.00,5
36002,6500.00,5
37734,45144.00,4
65410,11970.00,2
47352,8900.00,3
62159,10000.00,2
92803,6200.00,1
```

```
   "{0,25:n3}" -f "Household Statistics"
   write-output "--------------------------------"
   write-output "1. Search by Household ID"
   write-output "2. List all"
   $option = read-host "Enter a option (0 to quit)"

   $myarr = @()
   $myarr1 = @()
   $myarr2 = @()
   $id = @()


    if($option -eq 1)
    {
       $id = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Household ID "
          foreach ($line in $file)
         {  
           $line = $line -split (",")
           $myarr = $line[0]
           $myarr1 = $line[1]
           $myarr2 = $line[2]
    
          if ($myarr -contains $id)
       {
          write-output "--------------------------------"
          write-host "Statistics for household" $id 
          write-output "--------------------------------"
          "{0,-11} {1,10} {2,15}" -f "Household ID", "Income", 
         "Members"
       }
         elseif ($myarr -notcontains $id)
          {
            ""
            write-output "Sorry, entered Household ID not found"
            break;
            ""
          }
    }
```

Comment: Please give some examples of what `arr1`, `arr2`, and `arr3` might contain. What is `$myarr`?

Comment: Why store the details in different arrays? You'd probably have an easier time if you keep the relevant details together in one. Can you show us how you read and parse `household.dat`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not reading from a file as CSV, but somehow created 3 (same-length) arrays, you can start your code by combining the array values into workable objects like this:

```
$data = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $myarr.Count; $i++) {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        ID      = $myarr[$i]
        Income  = $myarr1[$i]
        Members = $myarr2[$i]
    }
}
```

However, reading your question a couple of times over, and looking at the examples you give for the 3 arrays, it seems to me that your file `household.dat` is in fact a CSV file without headers.
Instead of reading that file with Get-Content and then loop over the lines, manually splitting them on the comma as in your code, you should use `Import-Csv`, so you will obtain an array of **objects** where each object has both the 'ID', the 'Income' AND the corresponding 'Members' properties, nicely packed together.

In that case just do:

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path 'X:\somewhere\household.dat' -Header ID, Income, Members
```

Then your code would be much simpler like:

```
# loop over the records in the $data
$id = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Household ID"
# see if you can find a matching record
$record = $data | Where-Object { $_.ID -eq $id }
if ($record) {
    Write-Host "--------------------------------"
    Write-Host "Statistics for household $id"
    Write-Host "--------------------------------"
    "{0,-11} {1,10} {2,15}" -f $record.ID, $record.Income, $record.Members
}
else {
    ""
    Write-Host "Sorry, entered Household ID '$id' not found"
    ""
}
```